# Why is ${\left\| . \right\|_1}$(the maximum column sum norm) unitarily invariant matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is ${\left\| . \right\|_1}$(the maximum column sum norm) unitarily invariant matrix norm?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: By "unitarily invariant" do you mean that $\| U M U^{-1} \| _1 = \| M \| _1$ whenever $U$ is unitary?

Comment: @Alex M. Let $U$ be unitary matrix If ${\left\| {UM} \right\|_1} = {\left\| M \right\|_1}$ then ${\left\| . \right\|_1}$ is unitarily invariant. Is this true?

Comment: @Kanjo: It is false, take a look at Giuseppe Negro's answer below (where $M$ is the identity matrix and $U$ is explicitly given).

Answer (score 3):

This is false. The identity matrix has 1-norm $1$. But not all unitary matrices have norm $1$, consider for instance the 2x2 example 
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1& 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$